# Nim-lang: list comprehension with two variables

Tags: nim-lang

Confused on how to perform a list comprehension using two variables.

Here's what i'm trying to do so far:

```
let profile_row = lc[profile[r][c] | ( r <- 0..<4, c <- 0..<k ), int]
```

Here's the error:

```
greedy_motif_ba2d.nim(22, 40) Error: type mismatch: got <seq[int], float>
```

How is this correctly done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Nim 1.2 lc has been removed so here's how to do this for anyone searching today:

```
let profile_row = collect(newSeq):
  for r in 0..<4:
    for c in 0..<4:
      profile[r][c]
```

note `collect` removes the need to specify the type of of `profile[r][c]` but requires you to supply an initialization proc for the container `profile_row`

Comment: The need for `newSeq` will be removed in 1.6

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the way I did it does actually work, just needed to change the type.

```
let profile_row = lc[profile[r][c] | ( r <- 0..<4, c <- 0..<k ), float]
```

Comment: This might help to understand what type needs to be set in that last argument: https://scripter.co/notes/nim/#list-comprehension.